If someone has dual EU/UK citizenship, is any record made of their travel between the UK and France?
As above. When their passport is scanned, will there be any record of their movements between the UK and the Schengen zone?

Could you specify the "who"? Google probably is keeping the travel record (but probably without using the scan of your passport, but I'm also not sure about it, and in any case on cookies you have "agreed" to track your physical location.). If you are a suspect terrorist, both states will record you. Airlines may also keep record of you. The question is general

Most countries do collect entry and exit data  at their borders including their own citizens. The means of collection, what exactly is collected and how it's stored or used is generally not public knowledge. But yes, its highly likely that some record about your travels is recorded.

On top of entry checks by the Border Force, the UK government requires transporters to collect and share data on all people entering and leaving the UK (Advanced Passenger Information or API). There is no exemption for British citizens, see e.g. this description from Eurostar so the data is recorded and could in principle be archived or mined in different ways, including fuzzy matching across documents based on your biographical details (I don't think the British government publicly discloses what they do with it). I believe Ireland is also providing the UK with API data (to be able to account for people who leave the UK through the Irish border) but I am not sure how Brexit impacted that.
On the EU / French side, things are a bit murky. Some countries have long introduced similar similar Advanced Passenger Information Systems and there is nothing preventing them from maintaining a file based on border checks. So some data is being collected but because of the nature of the Schengen area and the lack of comprehensive data exchange, they cannot possibly track all movements. Police and intelligence specialists have explicitly complained about this (e.g. with respect to people coming back from Syria).
The EU has been preparing a new system (the Entry/Exit System or EES) to replace passport stamps and track entries and exits across the Schengen area for years but it is not yet operational and explicitly does not cover EU citizens. Its declared purpose is to enforce maximum stay rules for third-country (i.e. non-EU) citizens, not to track the comings and goings of EU citizens. That means that if you use your EU passport, it will still be impossible to get a comprehensive records of all entries and exits from EES data. On the other hand, British citizens will be required to pay for some electronic authorization scheme and should expect to be tracked.
Separately, the EU has also been working on a set of rules to standardize and generalize Advanced Passenger Information for air travel to make it easier to use by law enforcement. This would also cover EU citizens but I am not sure it extends to travel between the UK and France by train or ferry.
Finally, the Schengen Information System has a special category of alerts for “covert surveillance” so even if there is no systematic tracking or comprehensive database that could be queried after the fact, it is possible for a Schengen member state to request to be informed every time a specific person crosses the border. In 2022, there were over 160 000 such alerts.

Do you have a UK and an EU passport?  Which do you use to enter each country?  If you use the UK one to enter the UK and the EU one to enter France then successful tracking is unlikely.
I always use my Irish passport to enter the EU but primarily because it is so much easier and quicker.  I am less consistent on entering the UK.  For an EU trip, I don't usually carry my UK passport as the Irish one gets me into the UK just as easily.  However, I am not very worried about my trips between the UK and EU being tracked.
If some government agency is very interested in tracking you, e.g. they suspect you of terrorism or a serious crime then they will probably manage to track you regardless of tricks with multiple passports.

"If you use the UK one to enter the UK and the EU one to enter France then successful tracking is unlikely": because you don't think they'll be able to match the two passports despite their showing the same name (probably), the same date of birth, and photographs of the same person?

As long as individual border crossings are archived, tracking would not necessarily happen at collection time but could be done in a semi-supervised way whenever someone with the proper access and authority wants to retrace your movement.

I acknowledge that if there is a serious reason to track you then multiple passports probably won't help.  In more normal cases. how much data do the UK and EU keep of entries and exits of their own citizens and how likely are they to give it to other without a good reason?  Less common now with automated gates but sometimes I have entered both the UK and the EU with only a brief glimpse at my passport or passport card.
